# BigQuery regex remove/replace words from a sentence

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

How would I go about removing a bunch of words from a sentence?

I'm using the following code at the moment

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (Seller, '^Shop |Shop The |Shop the |on Amazon |®','')
```

Example text: the Seller Store on Amazon

Desired Output: Seller

Comment: Maybe you want to extract it? `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Seller, 'the +(.*?) +Store on Amazon')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Seller, 'the +(.*?) +Store on Amazon')
```

*Details*:

- `the` - a `the` string
- `+` - one or more spaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `+` - one or more spaces
- `Store on Amazon` - a `Store on Amazon` string.